# Number of Eastern Africa countries

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, geography, data-source, africa

Are Rwanda and Burundi part of "Eastern Africa countries" or "East African countries". Some sources are differing.

Comment: Just a comment on your edits. Rwanda and Burundi are two separate countries / entities. The correct phrasing of your question should use "are" for plural and not the singular "is". So "Are Rwanda and Burundi.."

Comment: @keagan,well the modal auxiliary "is" is the appropriate for the phrase for it shows singularity on each entity set and not "are".If you use the verb " are"in this case, you will infer that there are many Rwanda countries and also Burundi countries which is very wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because whether these countries **are** East African or eastern African has little to do with Geographic Information Systems.  Geography trivia is not a GIS topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would lean on this definition - [East African Countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Africa)

> East Africa or Eastern Africa is the easterly region of the African continent, variably defined by geography or geopolitics. In the United Nations Statistics Division scheme of geographic regions, 20 territories constitute Eastern Africa [UN Source](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/)

Comment: does that justify Rwanda and Burundi countries are inclusive in East African countries but not Eastern African countries

Comment: It's a definition based on a source from the UN to which these African countries are a member of. Most certainly, there could be an argument based on alternate sources as well as definitions. However, this is one that you could choose to be comfortable with if you think it is sufficient enough.

Comment: Rwanda and Burundi are within the Great Lakes region of East Africa. Surely then they can be considered to be countries of the East Africa region. Falling into both categories you have mentioned.

Comment: The UN list seems to be constantly changing, the onegeology portal uses it as the basis of it's geographic splits, and I see that  Rwanda and Burundi used to be classified in  `Central Africa` (i.e that's how they appear in the portal) but now  it is `Sub-Saharan Africa > Eastern Africa` and there isn't a Central Africa classification any more...